# Having issue with DateTime able to calculate day of week except Fridays

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a routine to identify if its a weekend or weekday but it fails to work correctly on Fridays.

I created a test program to see why before 7PM (19:00:00) the routine treats the day as a weekday and at 7PM and after it treats the day as a weekend.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;

MONTHCHECK:
my ($second, $minute, $hour, $dayOfMonth, $month, $yearOffset,
    $dayOfWeek, $dayOfYear, $daylightSavings) = localtime();

my @abbr = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dcm);
my $mnth = $abbr[$month];       


WEEKENDCHECK:
if ( DateTime->today->day_of_week >= 6 && day_of_week <= 7 ) {    
    print "$dayOfWeek is today \n";
    goto HOLIDAY;
} else {
    print "going to weekday";
    goto WEEKDAY;
}

WEEKDAY:
print "weekday section month is  $mnth \n";
goto END;

HOLIDAY:
my $h = "h";
my $mth = join "", $mnth, $h;
print "holiday section month is  $mth \n";
goto END;


END:
print "$date is the day and $hour hr \n";   
print "$date is the day \n";    
exit(0);
```

Before 18:50:00 I get the correct result of:

```
going to weekday5 is today 
weekday section month is  Jan 
29-01-2016 is the day and 18 hr 
It is now Fri Jan 29 18:50:02 2016
```

After 19:00:00 I get the following result:

```
5 is today 
holiday section month is  Janh 
is the day and 19 hr 
It is now Fri Jan 29 19:04:21 2016
```

Comment: Thanks for the DateTime catch. I dont understand where the break is with the goto with the else.

Comment: I have gone over and under the routine and dont understand how the GOTO is causing the issue. Can someone please help me with the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The code you show didn't produce that output. For instance the variable `$date` is never set yet your output says it was equal to `29-01-2016` at 18:50. Later, at 19:04, it appears to be empty as I would expect. There is also no code to produce the `It is now` line that appears at the end of both samples of output

The discrepancy is most likely because you changed your code, rather than because `DateTime` misbehaves after 7:00pm

Note that the weekday value returned by `localtime` has 6 for Saturday and 0 for Sunday, whereas the `DateTime` module's `day_of_week` method uses 6 for Saturday and 7 for Sunday. You should really stick to one or the other

If you think you have a genuine problem, then add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`, fix the errors that come up and post your new program together with runs of the *same code* before and after 7:00pm. That will allow us to help you further

Comment: Sorry the NOW if from  #my $now = scalar localtime time() + tz_offset($TZ); which I commented out. Not thinking that I provided the results from running the routine just a minute before my edit.  The other statement #print "It is now $now\n";

Comment: Thanks for you help> Looks like I will have to do some reading the the proper use of DateTime and clean up (as you stated) to be using one or the other as it relates to localtime.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime->now()` and `DateTime->today()` use, by default, the time in UTC.
If you are, for instance, in the U.S. Eastern Standard Time zone, this means that on Monday 18:59:59 EST it's Monday 23:59:59 UTC, but on Monday 19:00:01 EST it's Tuesday 00:00:01 UTC.

To get the local day of week, pass the time zone name (e.g. `America/Denver`) or simply `local` as the `time_zone` parameter:

```
my $today1 = DateTime->today(time_zone=>'America/New_York');
my $today2 = DateTime->today(time_zone=>'local');
```

Also, as others have noted, you really should start your script with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This will find several bugs in your current version.